# No adapter for endpoint; Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?

Tags: java, jms, spring-ws

I am struggling with an Spring-WS with JMS example. I set the Spring-WS and JMS wiring as per the Spring recommendations. But I kept getting following error. I dont know how to bypass this issue, any help will be highly appreciated:

```
[org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver] - 
Resolving exception from endpoint 
[org.springframework.ws.samples.mtom.ws.ImageRepositoryEndpoint@1c8b0b1]: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint 
[org.springframework.ws.samples.mtom.ws.ImageRepositoryEndpoint@1c8b0b1]: 
Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?

[org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SimpleSoapExceptionResolver] - Resolving exception from endpoint
[org.springframework.ws.samples.mtom.ws.ImageRepositoryEndpoint@1c8b0b1]: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [org.springframework.ws.samples.mtom.ws.ImageRepositoryEndpoint@1c8b0b1]: 
Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?

[org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher] - 
Endpoint invocation resulted in exception - responding with Fault
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint  [org.springframework.ws.samples.mtom.ws.ImageRepositoryEndpoint@1c8b0b1]: 
Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
```

My Web Service Wiring is

```
<bean id="imageRepository"
    class="org.springframework.ws.samples.mtom.service.StubImageRepository" />

<!-- JMS WIRING TO WS START -->
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />

<bean id="messageDispatcher"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher">
    <property name="endpointMappings">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
            <property name="defaultEndpoint">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.ws.samples.mtom.ws.ImageRepositoryEndpoint">
                    <constructor-arg ref="imageRepository" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="WS.JMS.EXAMPLE.V1.IMAGE.REPO.REQUEST" />
    <property name="messageListener">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.ws.transport.jms.WebServiceMessageListener">
            <property name="messageFactory" ref="messageFactory" />
            <property name="messageReceiver" ref="messageDispatcher" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My End point code is

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "StoreImageRequest", namespace = "http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws/samples/mtom")
@ResponsePayload
public String  store(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<Image> requestElement) throws IOException {
    Image request = requestElement.getValue();
    return imageRepository.storeImage(request.getName());
}
```

My Schema is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws/samples/mtom"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws/samples/mtom"
    xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="StoreImageRequest" type="tns:Image"/>
    <element name="LoadImageRequest" type="string"/>
    <element name="LoadImageResponse" type="tns:Image"/>
    <complexType name="Image">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

My Client Request is

```
<ns2:StoreImageRequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws/samples/mtom"><ns2:name>spring-ws-logo.png</ns2:name></ns2:StoreImageRequest>
```

Can some one help?

Answer (score 87):

I had a similar error message. My problem was in request and response class that I generated from XSD. It missed @XMLRootElement annotation. This caused that description of operation (in WSDL) and description of implemented method (in Endpoint) did not match. **Adding JAXBElement to my endpoint method solved my problem.**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://foo.bar/books", localPart = "GetBook")
@ResponsePayload
public JAXBElement<MyReponse> getBook(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<MyRequest> myRequest) {
    ...
```

See this blog for more details: [spring-ws: No adapter for endpoint](https://jbossadventure.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/spring-ws-no-adapter-for-endpoint/)

Comment: Thanks. This might not be the OP's issue, but it was mine.

Comment: Worked for me too. Here's example of my code:
`code` @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "ServiceCheckRequest")
 @ResponsePayload
 public JAXBElement<ServiceCheckResponseType> serviceCheckRequest(
 @RequestPayload ServiceCheckRequestType request) {
  ServiceCheckResponseType response = new ServiceCheckResponseType();
  response.setSystem("Testing system");
  QName qname = new QName("ServiceCheckRequest");
  JAXBElement<ServiceCheckResponseType> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<ServiceCheckResponseType>(
    qname, ServiceCheckResponseType.class, response);
  return jaxbElement;
 }

Comment: I don't see what @XMLRootElement has to do with the solution.  I also found that wrapping my response with JAXBElement helped, but that doesn't seem like something I should have to do in a simple framework like Spring.

Comment: Thanks, adding the @XMLRootElement to the JaxB Class generated from XSD worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a million, wrapping response in JAXBElement solved it for me. My example: QName qname = new QName("ResponseElement"); JAXBElement<ResponseElement> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<>(qname, ResponseElement.class, response);

Comment: Wrapping the response in the JAXBELement solved it as well for me!

Comment: With newer Java and the change in namespace for Jakarta from javax->jakarta can be an issue. I have the XmlRootElement specified, but it's the jakarta.xml.bind.annotation namespace not the javax.xml.bind.annotation namespace. I'm in kind of a catch 22 situation with this one

Answer (score 8):

I was using WSDL file and did as below, then it worked.

```
  @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://www.myservice/v1.0/query", localPart = "queryRequest")
  @ResponsePayload
  public JAXBElement<QueryResponse> queryAddrLocation(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<QueryRequest> queryRequest) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to " + queryRequest);
    return createJaxbElement(new QueryResponse(), QueryResponse.class);
  }

  private <T> JAXBElement<T> createJaxbElement(T object, Class<T> clazz) {
    return new JAXBElement<>(new QName(clazz.getSimpleName()), clazz, object);
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: @VladDinulescu you have to add lib for JAXBElment, and create 2 objects: QueryRequest & QueryResponse. Complie will be fine after this. The code I copy from my sample which worked for me already :)

Comment: If you return a QueryResponse and the method's return type is JAXBElement<QueryResponse>, no, it won't compile.

Comment: Updated the return as JAXBElement<QueryResponse>. Thanks @VladDinulescu

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error. the problem is that the request and response generated from XSD/WSDL missed the @XMLRootElement annotation. By adding JAXBElement to the endpoint solved the problem.

```
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "<targetNamespace>";

@Autowired
Service   service;

@PayloadRoot ( namespace = Endpoint.NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "name" )
@ResponsePayload
public JAXBElement < Response > Create ( @RequestPayload JAXBElement < Request> request ) throws Exception
{
ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory ( );
Response response = new Response ( );
Request req = request.getValue ( );

response  = this.service.call( req);

return factory.createResponse ( response );
}
```

Comment: I have done that but gave me another error: "Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath."

Comment: @VincentGuyard to fix that you need to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51916222/912829

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your complete Endpoint looks, but the class should be annotated with `@Endpoint` or it should implement `MessageHandler` or `PayloadEndpoint`.

On other thing you can play with is the method signature. Spring-WS' endpoint mapping is pretty intelligent: it tries to map input and output classes from your method signature with the WSDL file. Are you sure a String is the @ResponsePayLoad, not a `StoreImageResponse`?

For example, here's the method signature of one of my endpoint

```
@PayloadRoot(
    localPart = "GetHiredCandidatesRequest", 
    namespace = DEFAULT_NAMESPACE
)
@ResponsePayload
public GetHiredCandidatesResponse getCandidates (
    @RequestPayload GetHiredCandidatesRequest getCandidate,
    MessageContext messageContext) {
    ...
}
```

Which is defined in my WSDL like this:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetHiredCandidates">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:GetHiredCandidatesRequest" name="GetHiredCandidatesRequest"></wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:GetHiredCandidatesResponse" name="GetHiredCandidatesResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Do you see how it's mapped? Perhaps you're missing something like that in your signature.

Answer (score 1):

This method works when called from SOAPUI:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getOrderDetail")
public @ResponsePayload JAXBElement<OrderDetailResponse> getOrderDetail(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<String> customerId, @RequestPayload JAXBElement<String> promoCode)
```

In the method below, the values inside the customerStatusRequest are coming in null even though from SOAPUI I am populating them.

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCustomerStatus")
public @ResponsePayload
JAXBElement<CustomerStatusResponse> getCustomerStatus(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<CustomerStatusRequest> customerStatusRequest)
```

(CustomerStatusRequest implements Serializable)

It appears String parameter values are making it through the call. But not a custom class.
I annotated the CustomerStatusRequest class in this manner:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CustomerStatusRequest", propOrder = {
    "customerId",
    "gender",
    "dob",
    "lastName",
    "sourceSystemId"
},namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/webservices")
```

and also each field in the CustomerStatusRequest this way:

```
@XmlElement(name = "customerId", required = true, nillable = true)
```

The method is called but the values for customerId, etc... are still coming in as null. Are additional annotations needed for a custom class?

--Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What creating a problem for me is imports :

old imports are from javax

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
```

changed imports are from jakarta:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
```

just by replacing the javax to jakarta it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

First, as per the guidelines, there should be an **Endpoint** class

```
@Endpoint
public class EmpEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private EmpService empService;

    //This is like @RequestMapping of Spring MVC    
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "EmpServiceRequest", namespace = "http://www.example.org/")
    @ResponsePayload
    public EmpServiceResponse getemployeeDetails(@RequestPayload EmpServiceRequest request) {
        EmpServiceResponse response = new ObjectFactory().createEmpServiceResponse();
        List<Employee> l = empService.getemployeeDetails(request.getName());
        response.setName(l.get(0).getName());
        response.setEmail(l.get(0).getEmail());
        return response;
    }
}
```

And one **Service** and its  **implementation** class which will have **PayloadRoot** and other **Annotations (Request and Response)**

And place this in your spring-servlet.xml

```
  <!-- To detect @Endpoint -->
<sws:annotation-driven/>

<!-- To detect @Service, @Component etc -->
<context:component-scan base-package="your package for eg com.employee" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem but in my case was because I forgot to place the annotations `@ResponsePayload` and `@RequestPayload` in the handler function. Just check it! It's probably all it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but only running my Spring Web Service integration tests.

The problem was that I setup the `Jaxb2Marshaller` with a different configuration if compared with `Jaxb2Marshaller` inside the test. I was not using the same Bean for the application and test.

My `Jaxb2Marshaller` with the application running is:

```
private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.company.application");
    marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);
    return marshaller;
}
```

But on my tests, I was using:

```
@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan(ClassUtils.getPackageName(Order.class));
    marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

To make the test work, I just defined the two missing properties:

```
@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan(ClassUtils.getPackageName(Order.class));
    marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.company.application");
    marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added property     in beanXml file

And it is work.

```
<bean id="marshaller"
    class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
     <property name="supportJaxbElementClass" value = "true"/>
    <property name="contextPaths">
        <list>
            <value>com.xxx</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schemas">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/xsd/service.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Attaching the wsdl that is working fine for me.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://services.reactivestax.io/" name="UberPortType" targetNamespace="http://services.reactivestax.io/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://services.reactivestax.io/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://services.reactivestax.io/" version="1.0">
            <xs:element name="updateRequest">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:long"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element name="updateResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="result" type="tns:orders"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>


            <xs:complexType name="orders">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="customerId" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="driverId" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="orderId" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="orderList" nillable="true" type="tns:orderDish"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="orderPrice" type="xs:double"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="orderStatus" type="tns:orderStatus"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="paymentStatus" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="orderDish">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="customerId" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dishId" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dishPrice" type="xs:double"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:long"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleType name="orderStatus">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="ORDER_STARTED"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ORDER_ACCEPTED"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ORDER_READY"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ORDER_PICKED"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="ORDER_DELIVERED"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="updateStatusResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:updateResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="updateStatus">
        <wsdl:part element="ns1:updateRequest" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="UberPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="updateStatus">
            <wsdl:input message="ns1:updateStatus" name="updateStatus"> </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="ns1:updateStatusResponse" name="updateStatusResponse"> </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="OrderStatusUpdateServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:UberPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="updateStatus">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:updateStatus" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="updateStatus">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="updateStatusResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="OrderStatusUpdateService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:OrderStatusUpdateServiceSoapBinding" name="OrderStatusUpdatePort">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8091/service/uber-springws"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>


</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement in place of javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement for both @ResponsePayload and @RequestPayload worked.