# javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Tags: xml, exception, jaxb, bind, java-9

I'm trying to run my Spring Boot application on Java 9, and I've faced with JAXB problem, which described in the guides, but didn't work for me. I've added dependency on JAXB api, and application started working.
If you get the following exception, as a result of missing JAXB missing implementation using Java version >=9:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:177) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:364) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:508) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:465) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:366) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:107) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:100) [jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:169) [jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:106) [jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359) [jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) [jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) [jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) [jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) [jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) [jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509) [jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339) [jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) [jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) [jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394) [jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744) [jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4491) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:371) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-5.1.0.RC1.jar:5.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1252) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1240) [spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at io.eureka.server.EurekaServerApp.main(EurekaServerApp.java:21) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:70) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:174) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Marking duplicate as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279048/1746118 is same as what you've posted.

Comment: @nullpointer This question is not a duplicate. When people run into issues they google the stacktrace. In my case, I posted the entire stacktrace in the question, which proves to be helpful to people when investigating such exceptions. The solution might have been the same, but the questions, context, stactrace and the exceptions addressed are different. If the original question had bundled or quoted exceptions to expect as signs to apply this kind of solution, it would have been helpful. But no, that isn't the case, that's why the solution has got some votes up regardless of duplicate label.

Comment: Do this in a profile:

```<profiles>
  <profile>
   <id>java11</id>
   <activation>
    <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
   </activation>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  </profile>
 </profiles>```

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Add these dependencies into your pom/gradle:

**Gradle**:

```
compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
compile('javax.activation:activation:1.1')
compile('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0')
```

**Pom**:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-b170201.1204</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Jaxb is included in spring-boot-data-jpa 2.1.0 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: This worked for me but I see this warning:  `Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector ...  to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)`

Comment: Strange... When I run the app jar from terminal the error doesn't occur. It occurs only when I run the app from Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Note: this is a deprecated fix which also implies `Illegal reflective access` error. Look at Jakarta EE 9 solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52502208/547270.

Comment: You can actually use this `2.3.0`, not necessarily the minor version

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles upon this while doing the Spring Boot guide on consuming SOAP services (as I did): You'll have to also add these dependencies on the _server_, see https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-web-service/issues/40#issuecomment-540584682

Comment: For me, I was trying out many JAXB implementations, which was causing issues.

Comment: Driven me banana's this problem...until I did the above and voila, it worked. Why? I have absolutely no clue...Generated a Kotlin/Springboot project from Spring Initializer=> Gradle+Kotlin+SpringBoot v2.6.4...using IJ Ultimate, and no matter what I did in the Gradle build file, I could not get the test module, to be able to see the JAXB implementation until I did the above. Thank you and good night.

Comment: It works for Java 11 without **<groupId>javax.activation</groupId>**.

Answer (score 38):

Adding the following dependencies fixed the issue in my case:

```
    <!-- JAXB API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAXB RI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks!  The most popular answer did not work for me on Java 11 but this one did.

Answer (score 27):

For those seeing this issue more recently with IntelliJ and Java 17

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8):

Since I ran into this exact issue, and this is the first SO question that pops up on Google, I'll add my solution since I spent a good 8 hours trying to resolve the issue and couldn't find the answer here.

Some context: We're using Java 17, Spring boot 3.0.2.
In our pom we have

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Since we let Spring manage the versions we get

```
org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.1
jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0
```

We use the glassfish implementation, so our ClassCastException was slightly different
`java.lang.classnotfoundexception: "org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.contextfactory"`

In our case, the issue was that we had wrapped the unmarshal call in a CompletableFuture, which leads to class loader issues related to how the ForkJoinPool works.
Once we understood that, we found quite a lot of related issues, [like this one.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15737)

The solution for us was to pass a classloader as a second argument when creating the JAXBContext, like so:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext =
                  JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class.getPackageName(), MyClass.class.getClassLoader());
```

This finally resolved the issue

Comment: This solution also works when using jaxb from an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this today for another reason.
The app was supposed to run on Java **8** but I was running it on Java **11**, so yeah check that you're running the proper version of Java.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a very different root cause. After adding all the possible combination of libraries without success I discovered that, as stated [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393004/jaxb-class-not-found-with-forkjoinpool-java), executing the REST client within a custom ForkJoinPool affected the class loading process.

Other people seems to have suffered from the same problem ([1](https://github.com/zalando/riptide/issues/953), [2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15737))

Comment: Instead of a ForkJoin, is it possible to maybe reconsider your design? While putting the identified limitation into consideration as a workaround.

Comment: Using parallel streams solved my problem. It seems that previous developer tried to implement a custom thread pool like here https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on what library you are using. When using `org.glassfish.jaxb` this is what worked for me:

```
    compile 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:4.0.3'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.3'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:4.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked with me is changing the java version to java 8

Comment: I would not recommend downgrading the version of Java. It's like growing backwards into the past & not into the future.

Comment: @S34N it doesn't matter. We got what we wanted. For my worked 8 jdk

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For those using extra repositories, don't forget to add the Maven Central repository

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
    </repositories>
```

Then, add the dependencies

```
               <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added these below dependencies to get rid off this problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my set of dependencies to achieve a successful result

```
plugins {
  id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.0"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
  ...
}

dependencies {
  xjc("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:4.0.4")
  xjc("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.4")
  implementation("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.4")
  ...
}
```

openjdk version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **Spring Boot**, instead of adding `jaxb` or `jakarta` standalone dependencies, you could always just add `Spring Web Services` dependencies to the project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

- 

> I should you to use this dependencies if you are using **Spring boot**
> like a **RestAPI**

- 

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35474914)