# Java 11: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Tags: java, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I have a little project which does throw an exception when i let it run.

The problem is here (TestObject.java):

```
final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(...);
```

I really do not understand why this throws the exception. I also created a test which works like a charm (TestTest.java). Please forgive me the names, but this is just a small test application to get this working with java 11.

I followed this: [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo)
and added

```
compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
compile('javax.activation:activation:1.1')
compile('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0')
```

to my build.gradle but then it complains that

```
Error:java: module not found: java.activation
```

is missing. As this is also removed from Java 11 i added:

```
compile 'com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0'
```

but then it throws a lot of errors:

```
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.util from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.api from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2 from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller from both jaxb.runtime and jaxb.core
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.util from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.api from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2 from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.runtime reads package com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
Error:java: module jaxb.core reads package com.sun.xml.bind from both jaxb.core and jaxb.runtime
```

What is so confusing to me: the test works. So it seems like there is some kind of jaxb-implementation in the junit5 environment. 
I also found some other information in how to migrate a java 8 app to java 9 modules, where i found this:

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0359'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0438'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-xjc', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0438'
```

But this is also not working. I would be very happy if someone can help me to get that running.
I use java-openjdk-11.0.1.13-11.rolling.fc29.x86_64 on Fedora 29, 64 bit.

ps.: i wanted to write all that into the comment of the post with topic "javax.xml.bind.JAXBException..." but i was not allowed to do so. So i created this new post.

edit: the exception which is thrown in that sample application is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at test/com.example.TestObject.doSomething(TestObject.java:21)
    at test/com.example.TestObject.main(TestObject.java:12)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:269)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:412)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at test/com.example.TestObject.doSomething(TestObject.java:17)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:267)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: In java 11, these libraries were removed from JDK. You need to add the libs as dependencies. Check this: https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/#Removal-Of-Java-EE-Modules

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj i already added those dependencies. Otherwise, the application would not compile. For that reason i added org.glassfish.jaxb artefacts. If these are wrong, please tell me which one to use.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the first comment above. Adding jaxb-core and jaxb-impl to my lib directory solved my problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis)

Answer (score 24):

The solution is very easy. First, use jaxb 2.3.1. The beta-stuff is for testing only.
The real problem was the module-info.java. It is required to have 2 entries for jaxb:

```
requires java.xml.bind;
requires com.sun.xml.bind;
```

The first requires defines the implementation, the second the API.

The only two dependencies required are:

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.1'
```

Comment: it's enough to define org.glassfish.jaxb as a runtime dependency

Comment: +1 for the point about using the 2.3.x version. I've been trying to get it to work with 3.x and it fails miserably!

Answer (score 10):

When upgrading to SpringBoot 2.5, I received the same exception. Adding the following dependency (Maven) solved my issues:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to complete the other answers:

JAXB uses the classloader bound to current thread to find the JAXB `ContextFactory` class (`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`), and in some cases (for instance with jetty threads), the bound classloader is a `PlatformClassLoader`, which has the particularity to **not being aware of class-path**, contrary to the `AppClassLoader`.

To solve this issue JAXB API and runtime must be in the **module-path** (which is accessible by `PlatformClassLoader`).

For instance app is packaged with following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

So the application should be started with `jaxb-runtime` and its module dependencies, as below:

```sh
### Set the module-path
MODULEPATH="./lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar"
MODULEPATH="${MODULEPATH}:./lib/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar"
MODULEPATH="${MODULEPATH}:./lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar"
MODULEPATH="${MODULEPATH}:./lib/txw2-2.3.3.jar"
MODULEPATH="${MODULEPATH}:./lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar"

java --module-path ${MODULEPATH} --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH [...]
```

> Note: ALL-MODULE-PATH could be replaced by specific module names

Comment: Could you please check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70466801/how-to-convert-xml-to-string-with-jaxb-and-spring-boot? I have AppClassLoader as you can see in the stacktrace provided but I'sm still getting `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath`.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi when using AppClassLoader you just need the JAXB API and Inplementation to be in the classpath. In your case, I suggest you to add the jaxb-runtime from glassfish, instead of the one from Sun (which is more or less deprecated if I remember well)

Comment: I was using that one from Glassfish, but I was still getting the same error.

Comment: I suggest upgrading both dependencies to 3.0.1

Answer (score 4):

I found there to be a ClassLoader bug, especially if you're doing work within a thread via a ForkJoinPool or similar.  The bug is listed here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-api/issues/78

Creating the JaxbContext statically will force the correct ClassLoader to be used, but it's hacky. :/

Comment: For me this was also the issue, it only appeared when running JaxbContext in multiple threads. 

Solution that I would suggest is to define JaxbContext as a separate dependency or Spring bean and also as a bonus, it is recommended by Oracle to only create JaxbContext once anyway: https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#other-miscellaneous-topics-performance-and-thread-safety

Comment: If using Spring, I ended up creating a JaxbContextFactory component that I autowired around to the places I need access to the contexts.  The constructor of the factory stored off the Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() into a class variable, and uses a ConcurrentHashMap for caching new instances.

New requests will lazy load a new context against that stored off class loader and cache the result in a map for subsequent calls.  That was as close as I could get to a clean-ish solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is coming because of multiple versions not able to define definition.

Solution: delete `com.sun.xml` folder from your local m2 repository, and download only one dependency.

javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:"latest-version" in pom/gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Removed maven-dependency `com.sun.xml.bind` from my external library which is not modular and a lot of errors like `the unnamed module reads package com.sun.xml.bind.util` has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `Moxy` and I was getting this error even after adding the `jaxb.properties` file. So I had to make sure followings:

Following are `dependency`:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Along with dependency its important to make sure that `Moxy` uses the `jaxb.properties` file during the `compilatation` which is present within the same package. So add the following above the `dependencies` within the `pom.xml`:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
```

Evertything together would be something like this:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the implementation of OAuth2 with Spring 2.5.3, along with the dependency of OAuth2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

use of following dependency will remove the error
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:822) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for Java 11 - Gradle and below dependencies resolved it

```
compileOnly 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
compileOnly 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1' code here
```