# Why does Java 11 gives TaskExecutionException in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So, I'm working on one large existing company project, where things are old / deprecated and I'm trying to improve it step by step.

Right now I'm trying to update JDK version from Java 1.8 to Java 11. So I made changes from Android Studio preference settings.

Also I made this changes as well: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#java-11

**About my project:**

targetSDKVersion: 30

Android Studio: Latest stable release

Project codeing: 50% code Java and 50% code Kotlin

So, when I made above 2 change and sync the project, it got successfully sync and when I try to run this this exception is coming.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
```

---

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptPlaystoreDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptPlaystoreDebugKotlin'
```

NOTE: playstoreDebug is a build variant name.

Answer (score 3):

Answer: Upon upgrading from java8 to java11 there are some libraries that have been removed. If one wants to use them they need to be specifically added as dependencies.

This question has already been answered:

[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo)

[Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis)

Add these dependencies into your pom/gradle:

Gradle:

```
compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
compile('javax.activation:activation:1.1')
compile('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0')
```

Pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-b170201.1204</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the answer. So I checked that answers which mentioned, that as well. Can you tell me which libraries that have been removed? And is this happening because I'm using maven {} in my project inside build.gradle (project) that's why?

Comment: These are the libraries that you should look out for moving to Java11:
    java.activation with javax.activation package
    java.corba with javax.activity, javax.rmi, javax.rmi.CORBA, and org.omg.* packages
    java.transaction with javax.transaction package
    java.xml.bind with all javax.xml.bind.* packages
    java.xml.ws with javax.jws, javax.jws.soap, javax.xml.soap, and all javax.xml.ws.* packages
    java.xml.ws.annotation with javax.annotation package

Comment: I am not familiar with your project setup, but if you add the missing dependencies then that should resolve your jaxb problem.

Comment: So Alex, I tried to search what is pom.xml file and people are suggesting that I should manually create pom.xml file in Android Studio, but when I created inside app level, I'm getting same errors. Can you guide me where should I place that pom.xml file, and I exactly copied this content what you shared, there is no other code in that file, so is that fine?

Comment: @SychiSingh You have a graddle error so it seems that you should use the graddle syntax only , not maven(it's your building engine, you have one or the other, not the both)

Comment: Agree with pdem to stick with the build system that you have, which appears to be gradle. Then you do not need to introduce Maven.

Comment: A clean project build might fix it.

Comment: @Eyosiyas Many times I tried, but that's not working

Comment: @Alex Hi Alex, so what should I do?

Comment: @pdem Ok, so what changes are necessary?

Comment: The JAXB APIs are removed from Java 11. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception

Comment: @Eyosiyas So do I make change of that which is suggested in answer or not?

Comment: Check it if it works with your project.

Comment: @Eyosiyas I'm not sure abt pom.xml file, how to create and where to put?

Comment: In Android studio, you don't need a pom.xml because Android Studio uses Gradle as the build system and not Maven.

Comment: A summary of this discussion: First, use Gradle, not Maven as Gradle is the default building system for android. Second, add the dependencies mentioned by the author of this answer. Third, if you want to continue this discussion, stackoverflow chat is recommended, because it's going too long.

Comment: @JustInCoding How can I use gradle?

Comment: Create a new Android Project in Android Studio, and then replace its app\src folder with the one in your maven project