# SpringBoot Xml Viewing doesnt work Even Installed Annotaitons

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jaxb, jax-rs

Although I apply the XML annotation, I can't get results in Xml format when I query it. Can you help me?

Although I apply the XML annotation, I can't get results in Xml format when I query it. Can you help?

I am also using the json plugin, I opened this result in the hidden chrome page

**POM.XML**

> ```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>com.javaegitimleri</groupId>
>   <artifactId>petclinic</artifactId>
>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <packaging>jar</packaging>
>   <parent>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>       <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
>   </parent>
>   <dependencies>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>junit</groupId>
>           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>           <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
>           <optional>true</optional>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
>           <optional>true</optional>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
>           <version>2.1</version>
>       </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
>   <properties>
>       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
>   </properties>
>   <build>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>   </build>
> </project>
> ```

**Owner.java**

> package com.javaegitimleri.petclinic.model;
>
> ```
>     import java.util.HashSet;
>     import java.util.Set;
>     
>     import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
>     import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
>     
>     import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
>     
>     @XmlRootElement
>     public class Owner {
>       private Long id;
>       private String firstName;
>       private String lastName;
>       
>       private Set<Pet> pets = new HashSet<>();
>     
>       public Long getId() {
>           return id;
>       }
>     
>       public void setId(long id) {
>           this.id = id;
>       }
>     
>       public String getFirstName() {
>           return firstName;
>       }
>     
>       public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
>           this.firstName = firstName;
>       }
>     
>       public String getLastName() {
>           return lastName;
>       }
>     
>       public void setLastName(String lastName) {
>           this.lastName = lastName;
>       }
>     
>       @XmlTransient
>       @JsonIgnore
>       public Set<Pet> getPets() {
>           return pets;
>       }
>     
>       public void setPets(Set<Pet> pets) {
>           this.pets = pets;
>       }
>     
>       @Override
>       public String toString() {
>           return "Owner [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
>       }
>       
>       
>       
>       
>     }
> ```

**aplication.properties**

> ```
> management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
>
> petclinic.display-owners-with-pets=true
>
> spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp
> spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
>
> spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
> spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
> spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.favor-path-extension=true
> spring.mvc.pathmatch.use-suffix-pattern=true
> ```

**RESULT**

[image]

**NEW RESULT**
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo)

Answer (score 0):

I solved solution by searching on website!

We should to add these codes to **POM.XML**

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

[**Source of the solution link!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo)