# org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am trying to set up a simple Hibernate program setup. Below is my file structure in eclipse:

[image]

Students.java code (POJO)

```
package com.Hibernate;

public class Students {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    
    public Students() {
    
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id =id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

}
```

Students.hbm.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name ="com.Hibernate.Students" table="students">
        <id name="id" column="sid" type="int">
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="sname" type="string"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <!-- mysql dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- database connection settings -->
    <property name ="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://http://localhost/phpmyadmin/</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    
    <!-- Mapping file entry -->
    <mapping resource="Students.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java code:

```
package com.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    static {
        try {
            //create session factory from standard config file
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            
        }catch(Throwable ex) {
            //log the exception
            System.out.println("Initial Session Factory creation failed "+ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
        
    }

}
```

Client.java code:

```
package com.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create session object
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx= session.beginTransaction();
            
            Students s1 = new Students();
            s1.setId(33);
            s1.setName("Assama");
            session.save(s1);
            tx.commit();
        }catch(HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in console as below:

```
Feb 11, 2023 4:37:39 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}
Feb 11, 2023 4:37:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Initial Session Factory creation failed org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.Hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    at com.Hibernate.Client.main(Client.java:7)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at com.Hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
    ... 10 more
```

How can I resolve these errors. I have tried specifying the pat of cfg.xml in configure(), but didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo)

Comment: You can also research [these related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Implementation+of+JAXB-API+has+not+been+found+site:stackoverflow.com).