# java 17 sb 3.0.2 , issue with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jaxb, java-17

I have java 17 and Spring boot 3.0.2 ,

i have following error when bringing up application

Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.AbstractJaxbMessageConverter.(AbstractJaxbMessageConverter.java:59) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:121) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]

my pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-certificate-truster</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudbees</groupId>
        <artifactId>syslog-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- HTML Sanitizer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
        <artifactId>owasp-java-html-sanitizer</artifactId>
        <version>20220608.1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

2023-05-13T15:11:05.892-07:00  WARN 36599 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/package/framework//WebSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.

- with linked exception:
  [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
  2023-05-13T15:11:05.899-07:00  INFO 36599 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
  2023-05-13T15:11:05.928-07:00  INFO 36599 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo)

Comment: Please use full names for products.

Comment: You are mixing several versions spring boot 3.0.2 and spring-security-oauth2 (2.X) that's simply wrong... if you define spring boot parent you should not define any of those manually only if you are 100% sure what you are doing... also for using the spring boot bom (spring-boot-dependencies)....also things like javax.servlet and jakarta.servlet... starting with spring boot 3. jakarta is the way to go... please check the documentation for Spring boot in particular the release notes for spring boot 3.X etc...also things like org.springframework.retry are complete form different versions..

Comment: @amit Where you able to fix this? Running into exact same issue...