# Creating XML from java Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

**I am trying to create an XML from Java object,but getting error "Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath." Please help me in solving the error.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/writeToFile",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String writeFileXML(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        try {
            File file=new File("D:\\vendorfile\\customer.xml");
            FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter(file);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext=JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
            Marshaller marshaller=jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.marshal(customer, fileWriter);
            return "Marshaller successfull";
        }catch(IOException ioException) {
            return ioException.getMessage();
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at this older SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the JAXB-Runtime dependency (since you only defined the dependency for JAXB-API and as pointed by the error message you get).

Starting from JDK9, the jaxb-related classes is no more part of the JDK

Just add the following to solve your error

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```